# Get column name which contains a specific value at any rows in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, input

I want to get column name from the whole database (assume the database contains more than 100 rows with more than 50 column) based on specific value that contain in a specific column in pandas.

with the help of Bkmm3 (member from india) I've succeeded on numerical term but failed on alphabetic term. the way I've tried is this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['APPLE','BALL','CAT'],
                    'B':['ACTION','BATMAN','CATCHUP'],
                    'C':['ADVERTISE','BEAST','CARTOON']})
response = input("input")
for i in df.columns: if(len(df.query(i + '==' + str(response))) > 0):
print(i)`
```

then output arise as error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): NameError: name 'APPLE' is not defined
```

Any Help from You Guys will be very Appreciated, Thank You . . .

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`isin`/`eq` works for DataFrames, and you can 100% vectorize this:

```
df.columns[df.isin(['APPLE']).any()]  # df.isin([response])
```

Or,

```
df.columns[df.eq(response).any()]
```

```
Index(['A'], dtype='object')
```

And here's the roundabout way with `DataFrame.eval` and `np.logical_or` (were you to loop on columns):

```
df.columns[
    np.logical_or.reduce(
        [df.eval(f"{repr(response)} in {i}") for i in df]
)]
Index(['A'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: It's a very nice example of using `np.logical_or.reduce()` together with Pandas! +1

Comment: It would have been nice to see what the actual output is from this.

Answer (score 1):

First, the reason for your error. With [`pd.DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), as with regular comparisons, you need to surround strings with quotation marks. So this would work (notice the pair of `"` quotations):

```
response = input("input")

for i in df.columns:
    if not df.query(i + '=="' + str(response) + '"').empty:
        print(i)

inputAPPLE
A
```

Next, you can extract index and/or columns via [`pd.DataFrame.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html). [coldspeed's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50923731/9209546) is fine here, I'm just going to show how similar syntax can be used to extract both row and column labels.

```
# columns
print(df.columns[(df == response).any(1)])
Index(['A'], dtype='object')

# rows
print(df.index[(df == response).any(0)])
Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')
```

Notice in both cases you get as your result `Index` objects. The code differs only in the property being extracted and in the `axis` parameter of `pd.DataFrame.any`.