# how to find the value in dataframe by multi condtition with unknown column and return the value position and get the next row value

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, conditional-statements

Goals: find the Equities, Fixed Income, Real Estate, and cash value

for data frame into as follow, the data frame is not formatted.
it looks like

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14
0   Introduction    Header  Name    Account Alias   BaseCurrency    AccountType AnalysisPeriod  PerformanceMeasure  None    None    None    None    None    None
1   Introduction    Data                                 USD    Individual  August 1, 2021 to August 31, 2021 (Monthly) TWR None    None    None    None    None    None
2   Key Statistics  MetaInfo    Analysis Period August 1, 2021 - August 31, 2021    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
3   Key Statistics  Header  BeginningNAV    EndingNAV   CumulativeReturn    1MonthReturn    1MonthReturnDateRange   3MonthReturn    3MonthReturnDateRange   BestReturn  BestReturnDate  WorstReturn WorstReturnDate Deposits/Withdrawals    None
4   Key Statistics  Data    3709.07513207   3896.873152794  1.45933833  1.45933833  202108          1.45933833  202108  1.45933833  202108  128.58  None
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
10657   Fee Summary Header  Date    Description Amount  None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
10658   Fee Summary Data    20210803    S******28:bond Ratings For Aug 2021 -3  None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
10659   Fee Summary Data    20210804    S******28:cboe One Plus Np For Aug 2021 -1  None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
10660   Fee Summary Data    20210804    S******28:nyse  -1.5    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
10661   Fee Summary Data    20210804    S******28:opra Np L1 For Aug 2021   -1.5    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10662 entries, 0 to 10661
Data columns (total 15 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   0       10662 non-null  object
 1   1       10662 non-null  object
 2   2       10662 non-null  object
 3   3       10662 non-null  object
 4   4       10635 non-null  object
 5   5       10578 non-null  object
 6   6       10576 non-null  object
 7   7       10494 non-null  object
 8   8       10490 non-null  object
 9   9       10472 non-null  object
 10  10      10368 non-null  object
 11  11      10368 non-null  object
 12  12      61 non-null     object
 13  13      25 non-null     object
 14  14      4 non-null      object
dtypes: object(15)
memory usage: 1.2+ MB
```

Here with a data frame after using

`df[(df[0] == 'Allocation by Asset Class')]`

then data frame output:

```
        0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14
10430   Allocation by Asset Class   MetaInfo    Analysis Period August 1, 2021 - August 31, 2021    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None
10431   Allocation by Asset Class   Header  Date    Equities    Fixed Income    Real Estate Cash    NAV None    None    None    None    None    None    None
10432   Allocation by Asset Class   Data    202108  3603.49 1274.44 50.3859757  -1031.442822906 3896.873152794  None    None    None    None    None    None    None
```

I Try

`Equities = df.iat[df.loc[(df[0] == 'Allocation by Asset Class') & (df[3] == "Equities")].index[0]+1, 3]`

Output

`3603.49`

Question 1

if i dont know the 'Equities' in column [3], how to i find that?

Question 2

The code looks like ugly, how to improve it

Question 3

why cannot use shift method

```
df.loc[(df[0] == 'Allocation by Asset Class') & (df[3] == "Equities")].shift(1)
```

```
         0  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14
10431   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: Q1: If you don't know which column 'Equities' is in and it can only be in one column, can't you just search for it in a separate step and find it's  column?

Comment: i try `[df[col].astype(str).str.contains("Equities", na=False) for col in df]` but i dont know how to return the column value

Comment: You have shown us three consecutive rows that appear to be related, is there some structure in the csv format that you can rely on and take advantage of?

Comment: Does [Get column name which contains a specific value at any rows in python pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50923707/get-column-name-which-contains-a-specific-value-at-any-rows-in-python-pandas) answer your question?

Comment: thanks  `df.columns[df.isin(['Equities']).any()]` is what i look for